# Is there a nontrivial distribution which is preserved under independent sums?

Tags: probability-distributions, independence

I am curious to know if there is a (probability) distribution $\mu$ over $\mathbb R$ with the property that, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables each distributed as $\mu$, then $X_1 + X_2 \sim \mu$ as well.

A trivial solution is given by $\mu(\{0\}) = 1$, but I cannot think of a nontrivial example. I suspect there may not exist one, but I am not sure how to prove it if this is the case.

I know a near-example is given by the class of normal distributions, as the sum of independent normal distributions is also distributed normally. But the mean and variance of the sum will be different from the mean and variance of the addends.

I think an argument for its nonexistence can be made using the central limit theorem, as one might consider a family $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of random variables all distributed as $\mu$, then by induction each partial sum $X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ is also distributed as $\mu$. On the other hand, the central limit theorem says that the average $\frac1n(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$ must converge to a normal distribution (under some assumptions about the mean and variance of $\mu$), which would imply that the variance of $X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ must grow with $n$(?).

Comment: (The "distribution theory" tag refers to generalized functions... so I edited your tag to "probability distributions", which is clearly what you wanted. :)

Comment: Thank you! ${}{}$

Comment: If $f*f=f,$ where $*$ means the convolution of $f,$ then $\hat f\cdot \hat f=\hat f,$ where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform. But this is only possible if $\hat f$ is everywhere either $0$ or $1.$ So you need to find the inverse Fourier transform of $I_X,$ the indicator function of some $X\subseteq \mathbb C.$ Then you need to decide when that gives you a proper PDF. There is also a case where $\hat f$ is not a function, but a distribution, thus allowing, essentially, the case $f(x)=+\infty.$

Comment: Indeed, using characteristic function, you can verify that $\mu=\delta_0$ is the only solution.

Comment: Sorry, the end should be “$\hat f(x)=+\infty.$”